# Не работает Design в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, design, preview

Доброго Вам времени суток. С наступающим всех. Скажу сразу, кидать камнями не надо, я новичок. Но столкнулся с проблемой: не работает Design в Android Studio после переустановки последней. Как исправить..? Всем спасибо за ответы.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47249696/design-editor-can-not-show-ui-in-android-studio-3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988102/errorcom-android-tools-aapt2-aapt2exception-aapt2-error-check-logs-for-detail попробуйте пофиксить свою ошибку

Comment: У меня на этом же этапе сборки падало. Я полдня бился. Оказалось иконка в ресурсах какая-то не такая была, шестеренка. Заменил - заработало

Answer (score 3):

В сообщении сказано "*Редактор дизайна будет доступен после удачной сборки*". Устраните ошибки, которые не дают собраться вашему проекту. Когда **Gradle** успешно завершит сборку проекта, все заработает.

Answer (score 1):

Открой build.gradle в твоем проекте и поправь значения (см. скриншот)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: все же не стоит указывать версии библиотек через +, это сильно нагружает и замедляет каждую сборку